# RequireJS dependency not working, but using as require it works

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require, amd, requirejs-define

I have an annoying problem right now and I can't figure it out why it is happening.

```
define(["some/file"], function(TestA) {
    "use strict";

     console.log(TestA);

     require(["some/file"], function(TestB) {
         console.log(TestB);
     });

});
```

If I run this, I have, for some reason the TestA is `undefined` and the `TestB` is fine. For all other files it works fine, it is just a single file. But it is like all others that I have.

Any thoughts?
Why it works using `require` but not as a dependency?

Comment: This typically happens if you have a circular dependency. Does the `some/file` module depend on the one you have included above?